# Where do you save the Aws.config file for the aws-skd gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to install the aws-skd gem:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

They suggest either ENV variables or their shared config file.  I have already gone down the path of secrets.yml and it works nicely so far.  So then I figured I could just use `Aws.config` which they state takes precedence over the former.  I took a guess and placed it in the `config` folder but that does not work.

You should be able to just call `s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new` but in my case the default region and credentials are not being stored / applied.

Where do I store this file or is there another way to do this?

PS I tried adding it in an initializer but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE**

Now that I RTFM a few more times I found my issue.  I will answer my own question below.

Comment: This is absolutely not the place to rant about your dislike of something. Take that to the AWS forums if you have to rant about it somewhere.

Comment: Now that I go back and read that a few more times I had a D'oh - Homer Simpson moment.  Somehow I read that as I was saving that in an actual Aws.config file vs setting the config with `Aws.config`.  Also point taken on the rant.  I will be deleting this question shortly.

Comment: Changed my mind about deleting this as I figured it out - I will leave this posted as it may left someone as hapless as me down the road.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the documenation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/#Configuration): `~/.aws/credentials` You can read more details [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs).

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason I read the docs as `Aws.config` being an actual file vs setting the config (D'oh!).

So I tried an initializer again:

```
#config/initalizers/aws-sdk.rb

require 'aws-sdk'

Aws.config.update({
  access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,
  region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region
})
```

I actual had tired this before but I thought it was not working. I did not actually quit and restart the console as well as the server - I just reloaded the console so the initializer changes did not get reflected. +1 to @mark-b for making me read the docs again.